# How to export Material UI with Figma to a web app?

Tags: material-ui, figma

Is there a way to export material design customizations/themes/pages done in Figma, and put them into a react web app that is also using material UI framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Desech Studio for importing a figma file and then you enable the 2 plugins `material design` and `react` to export react code.

Here are the github repos for the [material design plugin](https://github.com/desech/studio-material-design) and the [react plugin](https://github.com/desech/studio-react)